# What's the policy on linking to non-market apps?

Tags: discussion, linking, warez

Not that non-market or self-hosted apps should be an issue -- but what about "Warez"-type hosting of cracked paid apps, or of apps that have been removed from the market?

case in point -- the ShapeWriter keyboard .apk was pulled from distribution after a company re-org (buy-out). It's hosted in a few places on the web.

Should we, or should we not, tolerate links to such an .apk?

Answer (score 8):

I say no to warez/cracks.

Marketplace/Market Place aggregator links are A-OK. e.g. AppBrain, Marketplace proper.

Alternate Marketplaces are OK, as long as they aren't warez sites disguised as such

Google Code links are A-OK

Links to applications that are free, where otherwise they'd be paid for, not ok.

Links to applications retracted from the marketplace, not ok.

I think the same rules apply as those rules for program hosting.

Comment: I'd add that links to apps on alternative Markets, eg SlideMe.org should also be ok.

Comment: "Links to applications retracted from the marketplace, not ok." makes sense, but also frustrating, somewhat. this is why we need FLOSS !!!

Comment: @GAThrawn I've updated my listing based on your comments. I've not heard of Slideme.org, but it looks like a good alternate for different apps.

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you link to warez/cracks of commercial apps you make it likely that this board becomes NSFW to filters. That means close that question/comment immediately. This is a q/a about android, true; but it also needs to be on par with Stack Exchange as a standard.