# Policy on linking to questionable/illegal/warez download sites

Tags: discussion, warez

Per this question [What's the policy on linking to non-market apps?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43/whats-the-policy-on-linking-to-non-market-apps) I think we're all agreed that linking to an app on a warez-type alternative market-place is something we don't want to do.

How about when something like this question happens:

[Is appbucket a legal app store?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1113/is-appbucket-a-legal-app-store/4577#4577) - Totally legitimate question from someone who's seen a deal that looks too good to be true, and wants to know if the site is legitimate or not.

However he's linking to the site in question in the question. this obviously makes it easier for question answerers to find the site and investigate it, so is ok in the initial question.

In this case where the community have decided that this site definitely looks shady and appears to be distributing cracked, warez versions of apps without reimbursing the authors, do we want to give that site the exposure and benefits of a link from us? Should we go back and edit the question to remove the link and just leave the site name?

Comment: What about linking to alternative methods of getting free apps that are only allowed on certain devices/networks?

Comment: From the previous question, if they're on a legitimate alternative Market site, then OK. If from the author's own site OK. And then there's things like when someone on XDA pulls a custom keyboard or live wallpaper APK or something from a newly released phone's ROM, they've been allowed so far. From copyright terms that's definitely a grey area, maybe worth discussing more?

Answer (score 4):

Well, the link is using `rel="nofollow"`, so the site's not getting any googlejuice.

Just because there's a link to a site does not mean that Stack Exchange or the members of the Android Enthusiasts site endorse it, and I don't think anyone would think that.

Also, anyone who doesn't follow safe browsing is not going to be protected by us. Without a link it would be academic to find the site via other means.

If the link went somewhere other than what it purported to (*goatse* anyone?) then it might be a problem. As is I don't think it is a problem.

I'm interested in other opinions, however.

Comment: I tend to agree, but I really dislike AppBucket and am against giving it and any similar sites even accidental traffic.

Comment: I agree, all they get from us is incidental traffic. Just make sure users don't spam our system and we're fine

Answer (score 2):

Well, **if you have evidence that the community feels strongly about it** (was it flagged? downvoted? comments questioning it?) -- then you could edit the page to turn it into a code block and not a link, eg:

http://example.com

versus

`http://example.com`